Slope raster won't align with input DEM raster layer
Newbie to QGIS. I have a DEM file and I'm trying to run the slope tool to calculate the slope layer. The tool works but it outputs a slope layer that is in a totally different location than my DEM. I've tried matching the CRS, reprojecting, align rasters tool (doesn't work). When I click "Zoom to layer" for my DEM and match it with the base map, it's exactly where I want it (like in the right state). When I click zoom to layer for the Slope layer it shows the slope layer floating in white space and the base map as a tiny inset.

Please provide your CRS, your export settings, and your settings when it comes to loading new layers into QGIS.
